# jqueryGet height of visible portion of div function to be activated on mousehover

Tags: jquery, css, offset

The function computeVisibleHeight($t) computes the visible portion of an element. By visible portion I mean the part that is visible in the window, now I'm not sure how transfer that function in to the arrow div and make the arrow having the height of the visible portion of an element.

I've commented off the mouseleave function, works only on the second hover!!!! dunno why.
Please help.

- please hover twice the image half hidden on the demo

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ggvWR/7/

[image]

JS:

```
$.fn.tooltip = function () {
 var $el = $(this);
 var $w = $(window);
 var timer;
 var delay = 500;

 function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
     var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
         docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height(),
         elemTop = $(elem).offset().top,
         elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height(),
         result = 0;
     if (elemBottom > docViewBottom) {
         result = 1;
     } else if (elemTop < docViewTop) {
         result = -1;
     }
     return result;
 };

 function computeVisibleHeight($t) {
     var top = $t.position().top;
     var windowHeight = $(window).height();
     var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
     var height = $t.height();

     if (top < scrollTop && height - scrollTop >= windowHeight) {
         // first case: the top and the bottom of the element is outside of the window
         return windowHeight;
     } else if (top < scrollTop) {
         // second: the top is outside of the viewport but the bottom is visible
         return height - (scrollTop - top);
     } else if (top > scrollTop && top + height < windowHeight) {
         // the whole element is visible
         return height;
     } else {
         // the top is visible but the bottom is outside of the viewport
         return windowHeight - (top - scrollTop);
     }
 }

 $el.mouseenter(function (e) {
     timer = setTimeout(function () {
         var $c = $(e.currentTarget);
         var content = $c.data('content');
         var $ar = $('.fix-arrow');
         var $h = computeVisibleHeight(($c));

         var $tt = $('<div class="tooltip right"><div class="arrow"><div class="fix-arrow"/></div><h3 class="popover-title" style="display: none;"></h3><div class="popover-content"><article class="default"><h1>Anchorman 2: The Legend Continues</h1><ul><button>£10.99 Buy</button><button>£3.49 Rent</button><p>Hilarious comedy sequel starring Will Ferrell and Steve Carell.</p></article></div></div>').appendTo(e.currentTarget).hide().fadeIn(500);

         $tt.toggleClass('left', $w.width() < $tt.outerWidth() + $tt.offset().left);

         if (computeVisibleHeight(($c)) > 207) {

             $ar.css('height', $h - 63);
         }

         if (computeVisibleHeight(($c)) < 207) {
             $ar.css('height', $h);
         }

         if (isScrolledIntoView($c) < 0) {
             $tt.css('top', $w.scrollTop() + 120 - $c.offset().top);

         } else if (isScrolledIntoView($c) > 0) {
             $tt.css('top', $w.scrollTop() + $w.height() - $c.offset().top - $tt.outerHeight());
         }
     }, delay);
 });

 $el.mouseleave(function (e) {
     // $('.tooltip', e.currentTarget).fadeOut(500, function () {
     //    $(this).remove();
     //});
     clearTimeout(timer);
 });

 };


 $('.item').tooltip();
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the exact same thing.